# Highcharts: How to ensure that two column series starts from same point on X-axis ( visually )?

Tags: highcharts

So I am plotting two column series on time axis. columns in one series are wider that other series( approx 3X).

So what I want is columns for both series should perfectly overlap but, thats not happening. The narrower columns starts from the center of wider columns.

Comment: Here is the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/NVEeV/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want each 4 quarterly columns to line up with the yearly ones. The reason this isn't happening is that the yearly columns are centered on the years, rather that starting on the year. You can adjust this using the pointPlacement option:

```
series: [
{
    name: 'Yearly Returns',
    color: 'rgba(167, 169, 172, 0.3)',
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    pointWidth: 62,
          enableMouseTracking: false,
          pointPlacement:'between',
          pointInterval: 365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000  // yearly           
},
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointPlacement

http://jsfiddle.net/wMhJn/